# Auto increment in table (database)

Tags: database, auto-increment

I tried make a Tasks table, very frequent adding/removing items.
When the application live, the table used for storing queued task and dequeued it.

When the app interrupted (restarted), the next app lifecycle continues working incomplete tasks, and maybe adding new tasks again.

The table look like this:

```
table Tasks
{
   int ID auto increment

   // another columns
}
```

As we know, the id always increment even if we delete the previous record.
what happen if the id reached `int.MaxValue` and then I added some new records again?
Is the id will be reset to 1, incrementing to 2,3,4... searching for unused id?
Ff not, how to make the id rollback to 1 (or any free id) again?

Comment: Which DBengine? MySQL, SQL server, Oracle etc (version helps too)

Answer (score 0):

in MySQL

```
alter table tbl auto_increment=1;
```

But YOU have to run this command nothing happens on its own. or build it as a trigger before update/insert.  When a records is attempted to be input which will exceed the maxvalue of your ID, you will get an error.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html as more info

WARNING:
doing the above can cause problems with uniqueness or relationships if the earlier records remain.